# How to get rid of unknown image margin

Tags: css, image

[image][image]

I really tried everything, display block, margin 0, padding 0. That purple background is from image-container.

Comment: Adding `display: block` to the `img` should work.

Comment: Pictures of code are almost never as good as real code in a working example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image?rq=1